# making vertical paper-tabs from in polymer

Tags: html, polymer

i want to create a side bar using polymers paper tabs i want them stacked up and down not left to right. is this possible? if not is there another tab system i can use that can. I do not want to use links in my tabs.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, material design doesn't have a design for this...which is why you don't see this option on paper-tabs.

It would be cool if paper-tabs easily supported a `vertical` property or allowed you to easily set the `flex-direction` of the tabs. However, that would require some work. If you'd like to see this added, I'd suggest filing a feature request (https://github.com/Polymer/paper-tabs/issues/new) and see what the designers think.

Answer (score 0):

[paper-menu](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-menu) could be a alternative if features like the underline transition aren't necessary?